# Angularjs-$ngResource： When I DELETE something by id, it shows 403 error

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

This is the delete Button:

```
<td><input type="button" value="delete" ng-click="deleteUser(u.id)"></td>
```

Here is the JS file:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);


app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

    return $resource("/apis/:method/:id", {method:'@method',id: '@id'}, {

        query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}

    });

}]);


app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "baseRequest", function ($scope, baseRequest) {

    $scope.users = [];


    $scope.fetchAllUsers = function () {

        $scope.users = baseRequest.query({method: "getPageData.req"});

        console.log($scope.users);
    };

    $scope.fetchAllUsers();


    /**
     *   here is the delete method
     * 
     **/

    $scope.deleteUser = function (id) {

        baseRequest.delete({method: "deleteUser.req", id: id}, function (response) {

            console.log(response);

        }, function (error) {

            console.log(error);

        });
    };

}]);
```

Now when I click the delete Button, it shows error like: 403,Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

request info:

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/apis/deleteUser.req/2
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:403 
Remote Address:[[::1]]:8080

Here is the SpringMVC controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/apis")
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;


    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getPageData", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Page<User> getDatas(@RequestParam(value = "pageNo", required = false, defaultValue = "1") String No) {

        int pageNo = Integer.parseInt(No);

        if (pageNo < 0) {

            pageNo = 1;
        }

        return userDao.getPageData(pageNo);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/deleteUser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        System.out.println(id);

        if (userDao.deleteUser(id)) {

            return "1";

        } else {

            return "0";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `.req` in `deleteUser.req`? That seems to be the problem.

Comment: .req just a suffix of the request.                                                                                            <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.req</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a server side mapping issue but you can try passing a different parameters to the `delete` action of `$resource`. Try changing it from:

```
baseRequest.delete({method: "deleteUser.req", id: id}, function (response) {})
```

to

```
baseRequest.delete({method: "deleteUser.req", id: id}, {}, function (response) {
```

Comment: The same. I can get the full url in console as following:                          Request URL:http://localhost:8080/apis/deleteUser.req/1

Comment: Then it might be your server side mapping issue. Have you tried to hit the delete URL in a rest client like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?

Comment: Yes, I just directly  loaded the URL http://localhost:8080/apis/deleteUser.req/1 on browser, and the server  response nothing. So, I think that might be the server's issue.

Comment: No, don't directly load that URL in browser since your that URL supposed to be working with `DELETE` request only and directly hitting that URL in browser will lead it with `GET` request

Comment: Oh,I see. I forget that.

Comment: I just used the plugin to test that URL in chrome. Yes, u are right, the server side response failed. I have to check the server side now.

Comment: Also, do you see any output for this statement `System.out.println(id);` in your delete action at server side?

Comment: I have added the HiddenHttpMethodFilter in web.xml file.                                             <!--
    * PUT,DELETE
    *
  -->
 <filter>
  <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>hiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: No, the Console printed out nothing. And the plugin said: 503 connect failed

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer to solve this issue. The key is that while you transmit a parameter with a suffix URL(like /XX.req), then it will happen this error: the server side can't recognize this request.

For example:

wrong:  localhost:8080/apis/deleteUser.req/2

right:  localhost:8080/apis/deleteUser/2

Maybe I should try this:(I haven't tested it)
http://localhost:8080/apis/2/deleteUser.req

=======================================================

After I tested the ideas above, both of them worked well. Of course, we should user the last one.

localhost:8080/apis/2/deleteUser.req

so, I just exchange the position of the URL parameters like this:

$resource("/apis/:id/:method/", {method:'@method',id: '@id'}